# MidiUnavailableException using MidiSystem.getSequencer

Tags: java, audio, midi

I messed this up by accidentally answering this one:
[MidiUnavailableException in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762803/midiunavailableexception-in-java/6501060#6501060)

So, I am asking this question again.  It is related to the one above.

I get an exception when trying to use:

```
MidiSystem.getSequencer()
```

My code shows the following is present:

```
com.sun.media.sound.RealTimeSequencer@1ded0fd
```

I have tried all of the suggestions in the previous question. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I am using jdk 1.6.0_25-b06 and Ubuntu 11.04 with all current updates installed. I do not have JMF installed. The sequencer class is loaded. I have soundbank.gm in the audio directory under the jre. I have tried enabling and disabling lines in the sound.properties file. I have tried restarting my computer to be sure no other apps are using the sound system.

I get the following exception:

```
javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException at
javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getDefaultDeviceWrapper(MidiSystem.java:1078) at
javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getReceiver(MidiSystem.java:240) at
javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequencer(MidiSystem.java:442) at 
javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequencer(MidiSystem.java:348) at 
playmidi.PlayMidi.main(PlayMidi.java:57) Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested device not installed at 
javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getDefaultDevice(MidiSystem.java:1130) at 
javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getDefaultDeviceWrapper(MidiSystem.java:1076) ... 4 more
```

The funny thing to me is that other apps (Banshee, RhythmBox, etc) can play midi files on my machine. I guess they have their own software sequencer (not sure).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try the source shown on [How to play a .MIDI file in a new thread in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038917/how-to-play-a-midi-file-in-a-new-thread-in-java/6039086#6039086)

Comment: The very 1st line failed with a NullPointerException which means that getReceivingDevice() returned a null.  Any ideas?

Comment: Let me ask a dumb question.  I have been under the assumption that I could play midi files without a midi card, because other apps can do that.  I do not have a midi card in my computer.  Am I completely wrong here?

Comment: My bad (I think).  My machine has an 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller, and lsmod shows the snd moule is used snd_rawmidi.  I am no Linux expert, but I think it means I DO have a midi card capability.

Comment: Have you tried `MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo()`? What's the result?

Comment: Here is what happens with MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo():

Comment: @olivierlemasle I give up.  Will someone tell me how to do a carriage return in the "Add Comment" box.  I keep hitting the "Enter" key when I want to format, and it sends my comment prematurely.   Here is what happens with MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo().  I get an array back with 1 entry.  toString() on the array itself yields [Ljavax.sound.midi.MidiDevice$Info;@1e859c0.  On the array entry (the one and only entry) the follow results are obtained:  getName is Real Time Sequencer; getVendor is Sun Microsystems; getVersion is Version 1.0; getDescription is Software sequencer.

Comment: @olivierlemasle  Yay, my whole comment was added.  Here is another one.  If I pass the array entry to MidiSystem.getMidiDevice, the toString on the MidiDevice result is com.sun.media.sound.RealTimeSequencer@1ded0fd.  Does this help?

Comment: I have the same error here. it sais "Requested device not installed" to me, for default device.. I added soundbanks, but it does not resolves the problem

Answer (score 1):

Let's install alsa-oss. Than you can run your program with commands starting with "aoss" like:

```
aoss java -jar XXX
```

If you use eclipse, you can run it with aoss too. Than your code will work fine. I've just made an alias for it, for a symlink:

```
alias eclipse='LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 aoss eclipse-indigo &'
```

( LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR is a solution for an other bug. There were some random crashes of jvm 2 or 3 / 10 hours. )

An other solution is when you install a built in java from the repository it would work as well